# Update ImageView Android

Tags: android, eclipse, imageview

In the onCreate event i make an asynchronous request to the facebook api :

```
Utility.mAsyncRunner.request(null, params1,
                    new myListener());
```

In myListener's onComplete Event i would like to set the image in an imageview

```
public class PhotoDisplayListener extends BaseRequestListener {

        @Override
        public void onComplete(final String response, final Object state) {
        //set my image with the url provided in the response
        ...parse json....
ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);


                URL ulrn = new URL(photourl);
                HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)ulrn.openConnection();
                InputStream is = con.getInputStream();
                Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
                if (null != bmp){
                    img.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                    setImage(bmp);
                    }
                else
                    System.out.println("The Bitmap is NULL");

                }catch(Exception e){} catch (FacebookError e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    showToast(e.getMessage());
                }

}
```

}

the problem is that the imageview does not refresh with the new one set by me.
It sets it, by it doesn't refresh it. If i lock and unlock the phone, the image appears as it should.
How can i force the refresh of the imageview?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't update the UI thread from outside (another thread). I would recommend you to call instead a method on your activity to update the ImageView.

Article about this topic: [Painless Threading](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2009/05/painless-threading.html)

Answer (score 4):

Use `img.invalidate();` to make the imageview refresh after setting the image.

Like this::

```
img.setImageBitmap(bmp);
img.invalidate();
```

Hope this may help you

Answer (score 0):

I watched over several posts before I asked the question here. That's not the cause because I tried it before. I assume that the problem is the way I display the image.

I have an image on the server which I am replacing with the image received from the client. The problem is once I send the image from the client the server image dissapears even though the image was not fully received.

I guess I have to find a way to fully receive the image first, and just after to do img.SetBitmap(bmp);